# Connecting node client side to maven server side

Tags: java, node.js, maven

I made a maven project and coded both client side and server side on this maven project.

Server side code is in `src/main/java` and client side code is in `src/main/webapp`, so when I go to `localhost:8080/example`, I can use my `project/application`.

Now, I'm trying to move the client side code to a node project and use `localhost:3000` to communicate with my server side java on maven project.

I've been googling a lot and nothing seems to work. Below is part of my code that I think is the problem...

```
function loadLogin() {
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById('view').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        document.getElementById('navbar').style.display = 'none';
        loadLoginInfo();
    }
}
console.log('GET request - login.view');
xhr.open('GET', 'login.view', true);
xhr.send();
```

}

```
public String process(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
    System.out.println("[LOG] - Processing request with RequestViewHelper.process(): " + req.getRequestURI());

    switch(req.getRequestURI()) {

    case "/ProjectOne/login.view":
        return "pages/login.html";
```

}

This is part of the code to get the login to work on my maven project(client + server).

Bu when I move the client side code to node, I can't seem to have `localhost:3000` communicate to `localhost:8080`.

I tried fetching `localhost:8080/example` but it didn't work.

I would greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed some concept.

With Maven you're using an **MVC** approach, loading data from database and rendering them in a particular view. This mean that you've got a front-end and back-end in the same code base.

If you want to separate this two contents, you will need to change your logic.
You should build an **API back-end** (it doesn't matter the language/framework) and after develop your front-end using another technology.

For example you could create a back-end API project using NodeJS and a front-end with Angular. If you want to know something more about this way here are some informations [**Learn Mean STACK**](https://thinkster.io/tutorials/mean-stack).